# jquery custom events confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have read the custom events documentation of jQuery. Just when I started to understand that you can trigger those custom events yourself, and elements like a link or window own standard events like click, scroll or resize....

I was confused when I was reading the code from [unveil.js](https://github.com/luis-almeida/unveil/blob/master/jquery.unveil.js)
At the bottom there is the following code:

```
$w.on("scroll.unveil resize.unveil lookup.unveil", unveil);
```

What are those events doing and where are they set / triggered?
And what is a "lookup" event at lookup.unveil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [namespaced jQuery events](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/)

In jQuery events can be namespaced to make them unique and easier to work with.
Generally you'd add a click event like this

```
$('.element').on('click', fn);
```

but what if you wanted to remove the event from just one element and you did

```
$('.element').off('click', fn);
```

you'd remove the event from all elements, so you can namespace the event instead

```
$('.element').on('click.custom', fn);
```

The names doesn't matter, it's still a `click` event, but now it can be removed without affecting other elements matching the selector that also has a `click` event by doing

```
$('.element').off('click.custom', fn);
```

to trigger such an event, one would just do

```
$('.element').trigger('click.custom');
```

and it would also be triggered by a regular click, just like any click handler.

In jQuery one can also define custom events, which you probably know if you're read the [Custom Events docs](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/), and it's as easy as doing

```
$('.elements').on('lookup.unveil', fn);
```

where `.unveil` is just the custom namespace for the plugin, and that event can be triggered at the appropriate time by doing

```
$('.elements').trigger('lookup.unveil');
```

and as it's not a native event, it doesn't really get triggered by anything else.